# How to search and remove various string in array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with login data, where I need to remove various, user defined strings, for example, my array looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Date: 16/03/2015 20:39 [1] => IP Address: 93.136.99.89 [2]
```

What I want to do is remove "Date:" from first array element and "IP Address" from second array element.

Now I am using str_replace:

```
$lastlogindate = str_replace('Date:', 'Datum:', $lastlogin[0]);
```

But is there more elegant way of do this, and maybe, find defined occurance, and then wrapp it with  tag, for every defined occurance in string in array element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also still use `str_replace()`, but pass array arguments to it:

```
$lastlogindate = str_replace(array('Date: ', 'IP Address: '), '', $lastlogin);
```

For input array:

```
$lastlogin = ['Date: 16/03/2015 20:39', 'IP Address: 93.136.99.89'];
```

It returns you:

```
Array ( [0] => 16/03/2015 20:39 [1] => 93.136.99.89 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex to replace like this

`preg_replace("/(.*?: )(.*)/", "$2", $input);` by iterating over your array and replacing each value.

```
$input = array( 0 => 'Date: 16/03/2015 20:39', 1 => 'IP Address: 93.136.99.89' );

$array_output = array();
foreach ($input as $key => $value){
    array_push($array_output, preg_replace("/(.*?: )(.*)/", "$2", $value));
}
var_dump($array_output);

// this is the output
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "16/03/2015 20:39"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "93.136.99.89"
}
```

Hope this helps